# Not able to connect pyspark program to local hive

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I have hive set up using default derby database.
I have below pyspark program.

spark_hive_integration.py:

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

spark = SparkSession.builder \
    .appName("HiveIntegration") \
    .enableHiveSupport() \
    .getOrCreate()

print("spark:",spark)
print("type spark:",type(spark))
df=spark.sql("select * from emp")

df.show()
```

If I copy hive-site.xml to spark's conf folder and run
"spark_submit spark_hive_integration.py" it works fine using "spark-submit" command.

But when I run this python file as standalone using "python3 spark_hive_integration.py" command.
It throws error as:

> py4j.Py4JException: Method sql([class java.lang.String, class java.util.HashMap]) does not exist

I tried adding configs in above code like

```
spark.sql.warehouse.dir - /user/hive/warehouse
hive.metastore.warehouse.dir - /user/hive/warehouse
javax.jdo.option.ConnectionURL - jdbc:derby:;databaseName=metastore_db;create=true
```

But nothing helped me.

Comment: Workaround - Use `spark.table("emp")` rather than `select *`... The issue is the Java classpath, not Hive